# How can I auto-update a variable every 60 seconds and use the variable as a condition?

Tags: angular, typescript, automation, request

I want to auto-update a variable `maxReq` which keeps track of how many requests there have been send and every 60 seconds beginning at the start of the application the variable should be set to `100` again.

```
getData(URL){
  if(this.maxReq <= 0)
     // wait somewhow the rest of the time to wait until this.maxReq is set to 
     // 100 again

  // after this.maxReq is set to 100 again return: 
  return this.http.get(URL).toPromise();
}
```

For doing so, I have to keep track of the time and the variable `maxReq`, but how?
The time should be independent of anything and should count down from 60 to 0 from the start of the application until the end. Everytime the time reaches 0, `maxReq` should be updated and the time should be set to 60 seconds again - and this should continue every 60 seconds until the application is closed.

What would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let timeLeft = 60;
let date = new Date();
setInterval(()=> {
   const secondPassedSinceLastRest = (new Date() - date) / 1000;
   timeLeft = 60 - secondPassedSinceLastRest;
   if (secondPassedSinceLastRest >= 60) {
date.
      timeLeft = 60;
      maxReq = 100;
   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you for answering! How would I connect the time variable with the current time?

Comment: I updated the code. Basically, time left calculated on each iteration relative to the current time.